# Assign ID number automatically

Tags: java, database, jsp

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO emp(NO, EMP_NAME, EMP_TEL)VALUES(088000, 'JIMMY', *****)";
stmt.executeUpdate(strSQL);
```

I have this statement to insert a new employee into the database.

What if I want the employee NO to be automatically generated by adding 1 to the previous employee NO? How can this be done in JSP?

Comment: you need to query that emp table for max(no) and then add +1 ..use that value to next insertions

Comment: @Naren That is very likely to break in a concurrent environment

Comment: Then go n create it at DB end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not JSP, a possible solution would be to create an auto generated incrementing column (known as an *identity* column) in the database. Importantly, this avoids the race condition that exists with a solution that retrieves the current maximum and increments it.

MySQL example:

```
create table emp (
  emp_id integer not null auto_increment,
  ...
);
```

Apache Derby example:

```
create table emp (
  emp_id integer not null generated always as identity,
  ...
);
```

MS SQL Server 2008 R2 example:

```
create table emp (
  emp_id integer not null identity,
  ...
);
```

The `INSERT` statements do not include the `emp_id` column. See [`Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) for obtaining generated id if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **AUTOINCREMENT** option on the field NO on the database, or execute a query like `SELECT MAX(NO) FROM emp`

and get the max value

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your DB... I give you a mysql example.

```
create table emp{
    NO int unsigned auto_increment,
    EMP_NAME varchar(30) not null,
    ...

}


insert into emp(EMP_NAME,...) values ("Jimmy", ...);
```

Now you can ask mysql the last inserted id with

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can do this by setting "employee no" to be unique and A_I (auto_increament) in this column properties

Answer (score 0):

1. Check database Schema where you are creating table `emp` with `ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`
2. Then update the schema `strSQL = "INSERT INTO emp(EMP_NAME, EMP_TEL) VALUES('ABC_NAME', '321321')";`
3. Though it is possible BUT we should not do any logical operation into `JSP`. Forward all input in `Servlet` and do there.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to do.

1. Some of databases like Oracle has features like sequence, which allows you to increment numbers sequently and operates as atomic.
2. Set the column (possibly primary key) to auto increment ( database option ), and do not specify that "NO" in your query. That way, the NO column you didn't add will be added by database automatically.
3. You can get max values from database table and add 1 for new NO, or you can save those latest value even in file, memcached, whatever you want. The problem of this #3 is, if you don't make program to be atomic between GET LATEST VALUE, ADD 1, CALL DATABASE INSERT QUERY, multiple query can have same NO to use. It's OK, however, if NO is primary key since only very first update/insert query will executed and others query will be failed due to primary key unique violation... but problematic in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be going to solve your doubt in database and use this following query as:

**CREATE TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `emp_tel` INT(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**INSERT TABLE METHOD:1**

```
INSERT INTO test
VALUES (0,jmail,1234567)OR(?,?,?);
```

**INSERT TABLE METHOD:2**

```
INSERT INTO test (id,emp_name,emp_tel)
VALUES (0,jmail,1234567);
```

If you had any doubt give me comment.

And if your using the sqlyog to use the shortcut.

[image]

if your wants this method like following as:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(id,emp_name,emp_tel)
VALUES (0,jmail,1234567)");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

---

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(id,emp_name,emp_tel)
VALUES (?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1, id );
ps.setString(2, name);
ps.setString(3, tel);
ps.executeUpdate();
```